# How can I "expand" a list to be arguments to a function?

Tags: clojure, arguments

How can I make these three snippets work?

```
(defn bar [a b c] (println a b c))
> (bar :a :b :c)
:a :b :c

(defn foo [a & args] (bar a args)) ;; some magic is needed here.
> (foo :a :b :c)
MoralException: You're a bad person for trying this.
```

I have looked all over for how to do this.  I tried lots of things like `(apply bar [a args])` but that's an ArityException (which makes sense).  What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap arguments to `apply` in a vector.

```
(apply bar a args)
```

Intervening arguments are prepended to `args`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had to do some kind of flattening or something.